# How to resolve UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii codec can't encode character u'\xc1'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, amazon-s3, boto3

I am doing some processing on csv files present in S3

```
reader = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(body), delimiter=',', quotechar='"',
                             encoding='utf8', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, skipinitialspace=True, 
                              usecols=cols)
reader.reset_index()

csv_buffer = BytesIO()

reader.to_csv(csv_buffer, index=False)
```

It was successful for all files barring one. for which i am getting an error as
UnicodeEncodeError:  'ascii codec can't encode character u'\xc1'

please can someone help me out

Comment: You need to specify `encoding` for `to_csv`

Comment: The file apparently contains the letter Á (A with acute), which isn't supported by the default "ascii" `encoding`; you either need to specify an `encoding` which does support it, such as "utf8", or handle it in some other way (strip it, replace with "?", replace with "A" or another language-specific substitution, replace with "\xc1" or "&Aacute;" or another computer-oriented substitution)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You need to specify `encoding` for `to_csv`

Longer answer:

It looks like that file contains the letter Á (A with acute), which isn't supported by the default "ascii" encoding; you either need to:

- specify an encoding which does support it, such as "utf8", which is the most straightforward and best solution in most situations; or
- handle the letter in some other way (strip it, replace with "?", replace with "A" or another language-specific substitution, replace with "\xc1" or "&Aacute;" or another computer-oriented substitution), then encode using the default "ascii" encoding, which is suitable if the program that will read the CSV cannot handle an encoding which includes the letter Á (A with acute).